# Search within all partition - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

If i have a table like this:

```
Unique key.          Drinks
123.                      Soda 
123.                      Juice
123.                      Water 
124.                      Soda 
124.                      water 
130.                      juice 
130.                      water
```

And so on...

What I'm trying to get is all the unique keys where they don't have any soda drinks. I don't want to do a simple where clause because of the multiple row (instances per unique keys). Basically I'm trying to do a partition and within that partition search to see if there are any sodas in unique key 123, 124 and so on....

Desired output is to return those unique keys where there are 0 instances with soda

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm a bit confused--you may need to re-format your post.  You show two columns (one column with a letter, one column with numbers).  Yet, you are asking "within column A and C" -- that part seems to not match with what you are showing us.

Comment: I've edited.  Please take a second look. Thanks.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle and Postgres are different DBMS. And what do you mean by  **partition row_number()**? In both DBMSs partitioning is a way to segregate data a single table for storage. Row_Number()  is a psudo-column generated as the query executes within a window function, it does NOT otherwise exist. Please see [ask] and revise your post to describe the issue you are trying to resolve.

Comment: I'm using postgre

Comment: So what is the output you are looking for? And please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the table, including the partitioning definition

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query to fetch the results you want. This looks for any `Uniquekey` value which does *not* have an entry which has `Drinks = 'Soda'`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Uniquekey
FROM yourtable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM yourtable t2
                  WHERE t2.Uniquekey = t1.Uniquekey AND t2.Drinks = 'Soda')
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
130
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24c9c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your "unique key" is not very unique.  It is repeated on duplicate rows.

I would guess that you have a table where it IS unique.  If so, use `not exists`:

```
select uk.*
from uniquekeys uk
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.uniquekey = uk.uniquekey and
                        t.drinks = 'soda'
                 );
```

If you want this in one query, aggregation is pretty simple:

```
selet t.uniquekey
from t
group by t.uniquekey
having count(*) filter (where t.drinks = 'soda') = 0;
```